# R-markdown presentation webserver on a local server

Tags: r, network-programming, r-markdown, ioslides

I was wondering if there is any way to run and share within my network an R-markdown presentation that contains a shiny presentation using my IP and a given port. Knitting and sharing the html file is not an option as my R-markdown has a shiny presentation.

Very similar to the feature that shiny has:

```
runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server), host="0.0.0.0", port=1234)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved this issue:

```
rmarkdown::run("...", shiny_args = list(host="0.0.0.0", port=1234))
```

I still wonder if R is able to add semaphores and keep track of people accessing my presentation.